# Как сделать, чтобы код выполнился после завершения setInterval

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не могу разобраться, как сделать, чтобы код выполнился после завершения setInterval, если только не callback, чего не хочется. Например, так:

```
function someFunc () {
    var _this = this, interval;

    $.get('/path', data, function (res) {
        _this.output = res;
    });

    interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (_this.output) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);

    return this.output;
}
```

Или есть другой способ вернуть в значение someFunc () полученную информацию res?

Comment: Без callback функции не выйдет. Посмотрите в сторону promise.

Comment: дурацкая кстати идея вот так пытаться возвращать ответ от асинхронной функции... конечно output **кода-нибудь** примет значение res, но точно не в тот момент когда выполнится return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function someFunc (){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path', 
        data: data, 
        success: function (res) {
            return res;
        },
        error: function(XHR, status, error){
            throw new Error(error);
        }
   });
}
```

В одиночном использовании надобность в самой обертке someFunc() сомнительна

Comment: С проблемой разобрался, добавив еще параметр async: false